# joining 4 different tables to get the records - with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle is the database we are using.My requirement is to take the latest record from myResults table which can be taken by seeing the latest time in createdtimestamp column, now display all matching records from myTransactions table when **myResults.resID = myTransactions.resID.**
As i have to display records from 4 different tables i'm joining them..**myTransaction.transID and myFields.transID holds the same values and myFields.formatNumber and myTransactions.formatID are same** as shown in the database tables. currently my query returns all the records but requirement is first take the most recent record from myResults table and display all relevant records from other 3 tables with the above said condition.

Please find the sample queries in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/463aa/11/13
I tried my level best to make it work, but no luck, the corelated query is not working. But you can see the output of the other tables in sqlfiddle.

Please suggest what are the modifications to be done to my corelated query in order to show recent record relevant data rows.

PS:**output should display 3 rows as myResults table returns one record with most recent time and by comparing the resID of myResults with resID of myTransactions we have 3 rows and myTransactions.transID = myFields.transID and myFormat.formatNumber is equal to myTransactions.formatId.**

Its quite confusing and complex..please serious suggestions only as i spent lot of time and i'm not a database guy.

Please find the corelated query which should be modified in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/463aa/15/17

Below are the database tables:

```
create table myResults(resID integer,productNumber varchar2(20),resultNumber varchar2(10),midnum varchar2(10),sosnum varchar2(10),status varchar2(10),description varchar2(10),createdtimestamp timestamp);

create table myTransactions(transID integer,formatId varchar2(15),total integer,spreadStatus varchar2(10),status varchar2(20),description varchar2(10),ctimestamp timestamp,resID integer);

create table myFields(transID integer,fieldname varchar2(10),fieldvalue varchar2(10));

create table myFormat(formatId integer,formatDesc varchar2(20),formatNumber varchar2(15));
```

Please find all the tables with data in [code here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/463aa/15/17)

Comment: `"Its quite confusing and complex..."` Unfortunately, your question is more confusing than the problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Yeah.. i tried my best to explain the situation. I need to take the most recent record from myResults table and display the matching records from other tables. So to display those matching records myResults.resID of the most recent record taken should match with resID of myTransactions table , and to get other information from other tables , condition is myTransactions.transID = myFields.transID and myFormat.formatNumber = myTransactions.formatID. Hope it helps :(

Comment: Why did you remove the table definitions?  Now no SO user can even _attempt_ an answer without loading the SQL Fiddle.  Please review the guidelines for asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your SQL.

Let me list down a few:

1. `NVL(formatId, 'N/A')`

formatid is a **NUMBER**, so you cannot replace it with a **string** in NVL function.

2. `myfields.field_name`

The column name has syntax error, it should be `fildname` without an underscore.

3. An extra closing **parenthesis** at the end of the SQL.

I prefer executing the SQL in **SQL*Plus** to see the exact error and line number which makes it very easy to fix it.

This is how you need to execute, I already fixed the issue mentioned above:

**Declare the variables:**

```
SQL> var orderDirection varchar2(20);
SQL> var orderby varchar2(20);
SQL> var productnumber varchar2(20);
SQL> var resultNumber varchar2(20);
SQL> var sosnum varchar2(20);
SQL> var formatid varchar2(20);
```

**Assign the values:**

```
SQL> exec : orderdirection := 'asc';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : orderby := 'total';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : productnumber := 'B2B100';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : resultnumber := '100';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : sosnum := 'sos10';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : formatid := '203435';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Execute the SQL:**

```
SQL> select transID, productNumber, resultNumber, sosnum, total,
  2             NVL(formatId, 0) formatId, NVL(formatDesc, 'N/A') formatDesc,
  3                NVL(formatNumber, 'N/A') formatNumber, status, description,
  4             TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') timestamp, cnt
  5      FROM   (
  6        SELECT prodHistory.*,
  7               row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY
  8                 CASE
  9                    WHEN :orderDirection like '%asc%' THEN
 10                  CASE
 11                  WHEN :orderBy='productNumber' THEN productNumber
 12                          WHEN :orderBy='resultNumber' THEN resultNumber
 13                   WHEN :orderBy='sosnum' THEN sosnum
 14                   WHEN :orderBy='total' THEN total
 15                   WHEN :orderBy='formatId' THEN formatId
 16                   WHEN :orderBy='formatDesc' THEN formatDesc
 17                   WHEN :orderBy='formatNumber' THEN formatNumber
 18                   WHEN :orderBy='status' THEN status
 19                              WHEN :orderBy='description' THEN description
 20                      WHEN :orderBy='timestamp' THEN to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 21                      ELSE to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 22                      END
 23                    END ASC,
 24                 transID ASC
 25               ) lineNumber
 26        FROM (
 27          select prodHistory_inner.*, COUNT(1) OVER() cnt
 28          from (
 29            select mytransactions.transID,
 30                      myresults.productNumber productNumber,
 31                   myresults.resultNumber resultNumber,
 32                   myresults.sosnum sosnum,
 33                   to_char(mytransactions.total, 999) total,
 34                   myformat.formatId formatId,
 35                   myformat.formatDesc formatDesc,
 36                   myformat.formatNumber formatNumber,
 37                   myresults.status status,
 38                   myfields.fieldvalue fieldvalue,
 39                   myresults.description description,
 40                   myresults.createdtimestamp timestamp
 41            from   MYRESULTS myresults
 42                      left outer join MYTRANSACTIONS mytransactions
 43                   on mytransactions.resID = myresults.resID
 44                   left outer join MYFIELDS myfields
 45                   on mytransactions.transID = myfields.transID
 46                      and (myfields.fieldname ='AXPARR' or myfields.fieldname = 'AXPARR_P')
 47                   left outer join MYFORMAT myformat
 48                   on myformat.formatNumber = mytransactions.formatId
 49            where  (  :productNumber is null
 50                   or (myresults.productNumber like :productNumber)
 51                   or myresults.productNumber = :productNumber)
 52            and    (  :resultNumber is null
 53                   or (myresults.resultNumber like :resultNumber)
 54                   or myresults.resultNumber = :resultNumber)
 55            and    (  :sosnum is null
 56                      or myresults.sosnum = :sosnum)
 57            and    (:formatId is null
 58                   or (mytransactions.formatId like :formatId)
 59                   or mytransactions.formatId = :formatId)
 60          ) prodHistory_inner
 61        ) prodHistory
 62      );

TRANSID PRODUCTNUMBER RESULTNUMB SOSNUM TOTAL  FORMATID    FORMATDESC FORMATNUMBER    STATUS     DESCRIPTIO TIMESTAMP           CNT
------- ------------- ---------- ------ -----  ---------- ----------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ------------------- ---
     90 B2B100        100        sos10    10   1001       dispenser   203435          pass       B2B passed 2015-08-22 11:30:00 1

SQL>
```

**Update** The above query only a single row because of the filter condition on the `formatnumber` and `formatid`. To get three rows based on `order by timestamp`:

```
SQL> var orderDirection varchar2(20);
SQL> var orderby varchar2(20);
SQL> var productnumber varchar2(20);
SQL> var resultNumber varchar2(20);
SQL> var sosnum varchar2(20);
SQL> var formatid varchar2(20);
SQL> exec : orderdirection := 'asc';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : orderby := 'timestamp';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : productnumber := 'B2B100';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : resultnumber := '100';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : sosnum := 'sos10';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec : formatid := '203435';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL>   select transID, productNumber, resultNumber, sosnum, total,
  2             NVL(formatId, 0) formatId, NVL(formatDesc, 'N/A') formatDesc,
  3                NVL(formatNumber, 'N/A') formatNumber, status, description,
  4             TO_CHAR(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') timestamp, cnt
  5      FROM   (
  6        SELECT prodHistory.*,
  7               row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY
  8                 CASE
  9                    WHEN :orderDirection like '%asc%' THEN
 10                  CASE
 11                  WHEN :orderBy='productNumber' THEN productNumber
 12                          WHEN :orderBy='resultNumber' THEN resultNumber
 13                   WHEN :orderBy='sosnum' THEN sosnum
 14                   WHEN :orderBy='total' THEN total
 15                   WHEN :orderBy='formatId' THEN formatId
 16                   WHEN :orderBy='formatDesc' THEN formatDesc
 17                   WHEN :orderBy='formatNumber' THEN formatNumber
 18                   WHEN :orderBy='status' THEN status
 19                              WHEN :orderBy='description' THEN description
 20                      WHEN :orderBy='timestamp' THEN to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 21                      ELSE to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 22                      END
 23                    END ASC,
 24                 transID ASC
 25               ) lineNumber
 26        FROM (
 27          select prodHistory_inner.*, COUNT(1) OVER() cnt
 28          from (
 29            select mytransactions.transID,
 30                      myresults.productNumber productNumber,
 31                   myresults.resultNumber resultNumber,
 32                   myresults.sosnum sosnum,
 33                   to_char(mytransactions.total, 999) total,
 34                   myformat.formatId formatId,
 35                   myformat.formatDesc formatDesc,
 36                   myformat.formatNumber formatNumber,
 37                   myresults.status status,
 38                   myfields.fieldvalue fieldvalue,
 39                   myresults.description description,
 40                   myresults.createdtimestamp timestamp
 41            from   MYRESULTS myresults
 42                      left outer join MYTRANSACTIONS mytransactions
 43                   on mytransactions.resID = myresults.resID
 44                   left outer join MYFIELDS myfields
 45                   ON mytransactions.transID = myfields.transID
 46                      --and (myfields.fieldname ='AXPARR' or myfields.fieldname = 'AXPARR_P')
 47                   left outer join MYFORMAT myformat
 48                   ON myformat.formatNumber = mytransactions.formatId
 49            where  (  :productNumber is null
 50                   or (myresults.productNumber like :productNumber)
 51                   OR myresults.productNumber = :productNumber)
 52            and    (  :resultNumber is null
 53                   or (myresults.resultNumber like :resultNumber)
 54                   OR myresults.resultNumber = :resultNumber)
 55            and    (  :sosnum is null
 56                      OR myresults.sosnum = :sosnum)
 57            /*AND    (:formatId IS NULL
 58                   or (mytransactions.formatId like :formatId)
 59                   or mytransactions.formatId = :formatId)*/
 60                   and mytransactions.transid is not null
 61          ) prodHistory_inner
 62        ) prodHistory
 63      );

   TRANSID PRODUCTNUMBER        RESULTNUMB SOSNUM     TOTA   FORMATID FORMATDESC           FORMATNUMBER    STATUS     DESCRIPTIO TIMESTAMP                  CNT
---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ---- ---------- -------------------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ------------------- ----------
        92 B2B100               100        sos10        10       1003 Sigular              302123          pass       B2B passed 2015-08-22 11:30:00          3
        91 B2B100               100        sos10        10       1002 exedemption          280908          pass       B2B passed 2015-08-22 11:30:00          3
        90 B2B100               100        sos10        10       1001 dispenser            203435          pass       B2B passed 2015-08-22 11:30:00          3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help. Please suggest what are the changes to be done to meet my requirement.

Comment: @user3684675 That is all listed in my answer. Compare my code with yours and see the changes. i have posted a complete solution, step by step explanation of what needs to be done and how.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: your answer in my opinion does not answer the main question the OP has asked: how to the the latest record from the myresults table

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I just compared, sorry but my question was different, i need to show recent data records..I need to take the most recent record from myResults table and display the matching records from other tables. So to display those matching records myResults.resID of the most recent record taken should match with resID of myTransactions table , and to get other information from other tables , condition is myTransactions.transID = myFields.transID and myFormat.formatNumber = myTransactions.formatID.

Comment: @cha OP's query can never produce three rows, it will produce only a single row because of the join conditions. by the way, the output is the latest record on the timestamp value.

Comment: I noticed that as well. However I think it is due to the bad data sample provided by the OP. In my opinion if you have taken the liberty to answer the question you should as well address the problem the OP is facing

Comment: on a different note, [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) works with different datatypes just fine. it does it by the implicit conversion of datatypes

Comment: @cha Did you test NVL? implicit conversion has a precedence rule. you could expect an implicit conversion from numeric to string, but not vice-versa. So, no, NVL doesn't work with different datatypes. **And you should never ever rely on implicit data type conversion, it is a bad coding practice**.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - but i'am confused what changes you have done for my original query to get the most recent record from myResults table..and how it works with huge data in tables. sorry to bother..may be my test data is not perfect but will the query satisfy my requirement?? :(

Comment: @user3684675 See the last filter criteria on `formatnumber`. I have commented it out to let the rows not to filter on `203435` but to allow the other two rows as well. It should work on large data set too, it is only a select, so give it a try and validate.

Comment: @user3684675 Please mark it as answered if it helped you.

Comment: ok..but one last question..how to get the most recent record from table1(i.e.,myResults) as  my requirement starts from their.   .I need to take the most recent record from myResults table and display the matching records from other tables. So to display those matching records myResults.resID of the most recent record taken should match with resID of myTransactions table , and to get other information from other tables , condition is myTransactions.transID = myFields.transID and myFormat.formatNumber = myTransactions.formatID . @LalitKumarB

Comment: @user3684675 By *most recent record* if you mean the row which has the latest timestamp, then all you need to do is use `timestamp` in the `:orderby` value, in my answer I used `total`. I hope that is what you want, get the latest row from `myresults` table and get matching rows from the other tables. It is not that complex, all you need to do is execute the query with different orderby values and understand the filter predicate. Once you are able to understand the output based on the orderby values and filter predicate, it will be much simpler.

Comment: yes that is the requirement. It may be simple but as i'm a new learner it seems complex to me because of this nested query. Can u pls suggest. Thanks and appreciate your patience. @LalitKumarB

Comment: @user3684675 Use the updated query, should work for your requirement. In the beginning, while assigning values to the variables, put `timestamp` instead of `total` for `:orderby`.

Comment: Can you please update your answer so that i can mark as answered. Thanks. @LalitKumarB

Comment: @user3684675 Updated the query and variables.

Comment: The difference i saw is exec : orderby := 'timestamp'; u have executed in SQL command, but in real time i cannot do that , i need to modify my existing pl/sql block only to perform that. What changes to be done to pl/sql procedure to show most recent record from myResult table and matching records from other tables. Sorry for the trouble but you understand the real time scenario how it works :( when user give the request dynamically to view the recent records...Thanks. @LalitKumarB

Comment: @user3684675 At real time you don't have to assign the variables manually. The PL/SQL code will take it as bind varibles. You just need to use the SQL I executed. Rest declaring variables and assigning values will be automatically done in PL/SQL using bind variables. Values will be taken from frontend application.

Comment: @LalitKumarB -- I understand, but your pl/SQL block code is same as mine which is shown in sqlfiddle except that you commented some piece of code, but in that block no where logic written to get most recent record from myResults table and all matching records from other 3 tables. Now I'm really confused :(.  Appreciate for your help, thanks

Comment: @user3684675 Firstly, it is not PL/SQL block but pure SQL. Don't get confused with the bind variables. Secondly, If you are not able to understand the difference, then let me point it out to you: 1> I commented out the filter conditions at `line 46` and `line 57 to line 59`. If you do not remove these lines, your output will always have only 1 row as you are filtering only 1 formatid. 2> I added a condition at `line 60` to remove the rows having NULL values which are due to the **Outer join**.

Comment: @user3684675 3. You cannot run that SQL in SQL Fiddle because you are using colon for the variables which makes them **bind variables**, and bind variables can only be used in **PL/SQL** and **not SQL**. That is the reason I had to declare and assign the bind variables explicitly. There is no ay you can execute that SQL in SQL Fiddle, unless you make it a procedure and pass the values to the bind variable. So, forget the SQL Fiddle, just do the changes to your SQL as I have suggested and use it in your PL/SQL code